# How to convert ByteArray to Image in Xamarin forms

Tags: arrays, image, xamarin.forms, image-conversion

In Xamarin.Forms I have a byte[] array and I want to Convert that byte[] array to an Image. Any solution

XAML

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="80" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

ViewModel

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(byteArray);
var stream1 = new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes);
Image = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
{
 return new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes);
});
```

UI not rendered it shows only blank screen

Comment: What does `byteArray` contain? Because it looks like a string and getting ASCII codes of it most likely won’t do what you want

Comment: byteArray contains SVG image format eg: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><svg viewBox="0 0 150 37" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ........</text></g></g></svg>

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen any alternative instead of Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(byteArray)

Comment: Your regular Image cannot show SVG's in Xamarin forms, you will either have to use Skia or FFImageloading to show the image

Comment: I could show the SVG image dynamically am not saving the image in locally or my solution is that possible to do this? @FreakyAli

Comment: Let me try to add a possible solution

Comment: @FreakyAli any luck?

Comment: @DevXam You can't use the solution from the other answer?